# UIViewController isn't displayed in iOS 8 (but works in iOS 9)

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

I'm developing an iOS app in Swift 2 and I have a problem that I can't figure out, I think it may be a bug.

When I run the app in iOS 9 there is no problem, but when I debug it in iOS 8 the following happens: After a notification callback I call prepareforsegue(identifier), the identifier is OK, it enters the ViewDidLoad of the new screen but it never shows it.

Here is the code:
In RegisterData.swift:

```
func normalRegisterOk(){
        performSegueWithIdentifier("userRegisteredSegue", sender: self)
}
```

To show that the segue Identifier exists, here are 2 screenshots of the storyboard: 
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlCfz.png)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neAfJ.png)

After going through normalRegisterOk and calling performSegueWithIdentifier, **it does enter the ViewController of the corresponding scene**, I put a breakpoint in the viewDidLoad and the viewWillAppear and it enters in both of them.

What I can't understand is why **this scene isn't displayed in iOS 8, and is displayed in iOS 9**. This scene only has a label and a ScrollView. Does anybody has any idea what the problem can be? Any new functionallity introduced for iOS 9 that doesn't support iOS 8?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because the view isn't ready yet, call it in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mitley's answer I realized that it never entered the viewDidAppear therefore I started debugging and I realized that I called a function in viewDidLayoutSubviews and I don't know why it was called infinite times creating an infinite loop that was what didn't let the screen to show. I still don't know why this happens in iOS8 but not iOS9, but the problem was solved my moving this call to the viewDidLoad